# Regex interpretaion in Django tutorial

Tags: python, regex, django

despite being familiar with the basics of regex, the tutorial for [Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views) does not go into much detail about how some regex generates dynamic links. 
I am looking at this specific snippet under the polls/urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Could someone go into detail about how that regex is interpreted? The quantifiers at the start of the capture group, `(?P<question_id>` do not make sense to me. Specifically, how does Django know that `<question_id>` is a foreign key?

Comment: `(?P<question_id>...)` is only the syntax for a "named capture" group. Instead of using an index for capture group, you can use a name. Obviously `?` isn't a quantifier here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?P<question_id>.*)` Says everything captured by the regex inside the parenthesis will be in a named group called question_id.  It can be directly addressed.  So the regex doesn't know it is a foreign key or anything of the sort, just that there is a group named `question_id`.   The parenthesis isn't really matched in the incoming string.

The `[0-9]+` matches and numeric string 1 or more digits long.

`^` is the start of the string.  `$` is the end of the string.  `^, $, (?P<question_id>, and )` are somewhat meta and aren't impacted by the string so much as the string's position and how the regex extracted groups will be referenced.

The captured group is passed to the view (detail in this case) as a keyword argument and it's up to the view to make use of it in a meaningful way.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, so does that mean that naming it `question_id` is arbitrary and does not 'matter' to the regex statement?

Comment: I added a note to the answer.  It's meaningful in the sense that it is a keyword argument that is passed to the view.  If you changed it, a different keyword arg would be passed to the view.  Either would work as long as the view and the url agreed on the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The `(?P<name>...)` means that this regex has a *named capture group*, unlike the `(...)` syntax, which is a numbered capture group. Django takes the named parameters and passes them to your view.

Answer (score 0):

**`^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$`**

```
^ assert position at start of the string
(?P<question_id>[0-9]+) Named capturing group "question_id"
    [0-9]+ match a single character present in the list below:

        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, 
        giving back as needed [greedy]
        0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9

$ assert position at end of the string
```

Demo and full explanation: https://regex101.com/r/zV3rZ1/1

Answer (score 0):

It captures [0-9]+ under the name question_id. Then it passes the captured number to the view function as a parameter. You can try it with re functions. It is not Django specific.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', '122/').groupdict()
{'question_id': '122'}
```